# How can I make scrollbar on modal works in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a modal with progress bar, which should show progress on scroll.

When I first open it it doesn't work, it does only when i close and open the modal again. How to fix this to work at first time? I tried with different lifecycle hooks, but none of them worked.

```
<template>
 <div ref="progressbar"> .....</div>
</template>

<script>
methods: {
   chceckScrollBar () {
      const element = this.$refs.progressbar
      const clientHeight = element.clientHeight
      const scrollHeight = element.scrollHeight
      const scrollTop = element.scrollTop
      const res = (scrollTop / (scrollHeight - clientHeight)) * 100
      if (scrollHeight <= clientHeight) {
        this.percentage = 100
      } else {
        this.percentage = res.toFixed(2)
      }
   }
}


 created() {
    this.$refs.progressbar.addEventListener('scroll', this.chceckScrollBar )
  },
  beforeDestroy () {
    this.$refs.progressbar.removeEventListener('scroll',this.chceckScrollBar )
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I guest it is because `chceckScrollBar()` should be put in `methods`.

Comment: It is. I've just edited.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put your eventlistener into the mounted method, as the ref does not exist in the created yet

```
mounted() {
    this.$refs.progressbar.addEventListener('scroll', this.chceckScrollBar )
}
```

Comment: can you validate that this.$refs.progressbar actually gives you the object on opening the dialog initially? Maybe provide a jsfillde

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use `mounted` method to add scroll event listener. Example [on codepen](https://codepen.io/spigel-jack/pen/BgbpKd). But the problem is adding the js event listener ***is not a vue way***. You need to use  `v-on:scroll="chceckScrollBar"` on your element. Why? `on:scroll` always be called when the user scrolling the element.

*template*

```
<div id="app-vue">
   <template>
     {{percentage}}
     <div class="modal" ref="progressbar"> Hello 
       <br>
         ....
       <br></div>
  </template> 
</div>
```

*Css*

```
.modal {
  width:200px;
  max-height:300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color:green;
}
```

*Vue*

```
let vm = new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      percentage:0,
    };
  },
  methods: {
   chceckScrollBar () {
      const element = this.$refs.progressbar
      const clientHeight = element.clientHeight
      const scrollHeight = element.scrollHeight
      const scrollTop = element.scrollTop
      const res = (scrollTop / (scrollHeight - clientHeight)) * 100
      if (scrollHeight <= clientHeight) {
        this.percentage = 100
      } else {
        this.percentage = res.toFixed(2)
      }
   }
},

 mounted() {
    this.$refs.progressbar.addEventListener('scroll', this.chceckScrollBar );
  },
  beforeDestroy () {
    this.$refs.progressbar.removeEventListener('scroll',this.chceckScrollBar );
  },
  el: '#app-vue'
})
```